# Merge [benchmarks] into [benchmarking]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[benchmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmarks) (x6) should be merged into [benchmarking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmarking) (x73).

Additionally, there should be a new synonym [benchmarking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmarking) ← [benchmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmarks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Done.